# How can I run a ttest on the CEM matched data?

Tags: stata

I have run a CEM matching process on my data using Stata, and now I would like to know how to run a t-test on the variables of the matched data.

```
/* Simple example of my code; first I run the CEM */
cem age gender education, treatment(treat)

/* Then I want to have a look at the summary statistics of the entire population and the matched data (this code works fine) */
summarize age gender education
summarize age gender education [iweight=cem_weights]

/* But if I want to do a t test only on the matched data, I get an error with the weights */
ttest age, by(treat) /* works fine */
ttest age [iweight=cem_weights], by(treat) /* error saying that weights are not allowed */
```

How can I run t tests only on the matched data? An option could also be to export the matched data, so how could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
sysuse auto, clear
cem mpg weight rep78, treatment(foreign)
mean price [iweight = cem_weight], over(foreign)  //coeflegend
lincom _b[c.price@1.foreign] - _b[c.price@0.foreign]
```

Personally, I would just use regress with het-robust standard errors (which gets similar results here, and will get even closer with a bigger sample):

```
regress price i.foreign [iweight = cem_weight], robust
```